# crypto notes service

Tags: web-apps, plain-text, saas, cryptography

I'm looking for a online service similar to passpack.com but for notes, not for passwords. I want all the notes (plain text) has been encrypted on the server and decrypted on the client. The only condition note can be quite long, about 50 000 symbols.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does this service have to be gratis or can it be commercial?

Comment: @Tom it may be both, it is not so important, the main thing is functional.

Answer (score 1):

### [Shrib](https://shrib.com)

Shrib is a webapp for saving and sharing notes. It also has the option to encrypt them via password, email address, or phone number.

Requested features:

- Able to save long notes. [This is an example note with 60 000 dots](https://secure.shrib.com/Test60000chars). Password is `softwarerecs`

Comment: Thanks @Timmy I'll check it later. Sounds good to me